# Using a macro to supply pgfkey parameters

Tags: pgfkeys

I would like to supply the pgf argument of a particular macro call in advance. However I get the error:

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/test/name=test,
>   active=false' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\newcommand{\args}{name=test, active=false}

\pgfkeys{
    /test/.is family, /test,
    % Here are the options that a user can pass
    default/.style = {
        name = Unnamed,
        active = false,
    },
    name/.estore in = \testName,
    active/.estore in = \testActive,
}

\newcommand\test[2][]{
    \pgfkeys{/test, default, #1}
    \noindent%
    name: \testName \\
    active: \testActive \\
    text: #2 \\
}

\begin{document}
    % This works as normal
    \test[name=test, active=false]{ipsum}

    %This gives the following error:
    %Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/test/name=test, active=false' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
    \test[\args]{ipsum}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** dexteritas answered the question as stated very quickly, but I was hoping to find a solution for the following problem.

This is a sample of one of many files which I am hoping to simplify:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw ( 0,  0) node[anchor=north east](aa){\TalentBox[tier=5,  width=14em, active=\gritActive,            ranked=\gritRanked,            name=\gritTitle]            {\gritDescription}}
              ( 6,  0) node[anchor=north east](ab){\TalentBox[tier=5,  width=14em, active=\arcanaCasterActive,    ranked=\arcanaCasterRanked,    name=\arcanaCasterTitle]    {\arcanaCasterDescription}}
              (12,  0) node[anchor=north east](ac){\TalentBox[tier=5,  width=14em, active=\gritActive,            ranked=\gritRanked,            name=\gritTitle]            {\gritDescription}}
              ( 0, -5) node[anchor=north east](ba){\TalentBox[tier=10, width=14em, active=\gentlePreserverActive, ranked=\gentlePreserverRanked, name=\gentlePreserverTitle] {\gentlePreserverDescription}}
              ( 6, -5) node[anchor=north east](bb){\TalentBox[tier=10, width=14em, active=\disguiseCastingActive, ranked=\disguiseCastingRanked, name=\disguiseCastingTitle] {\disguiseCastingDescription}}
              (12, -5) node[anchor=north east](bc){\TalentBox[tier=10, width=14em, active=\potentDefilerActive,   ranked=\potentDefilerRanked,   name=\potentDefilerTitle]   {\potentDefilerDescription}}
              ( 0,-10) node[anchor=north east](ca){\TalentBox[tier=15, width=14em, active=\gentlePreserverActive, ranked=\gentlePreserverRanked, name=\gentlePreserverTitle] {\gentlePreserverDescription}}
              ( 6,-10) node[anchor=north east](cb){\TalentBox[tier=15, width=14em, active=\signatureSpellActive,  ranked=\signatureSpellRanked,  name=\signatureSpellTitle]  {\signatureSpellDescription}}
              (12,-10) node[anchor=north east](cc){\TalentBox[tier=15, width=14em, active=\potentDefilerActive,   ranked=\potentDefilerRanked,   name=\potentDefilerTitle]   {\potentDefilerDescription}}
              ( 0,-15) node[anchor=north east](da){\TalentBox[tier=20, width=14em, active=\lingeringSpellActive,  ranked=\lingeringSpellRanked,  name=\lingeringSpellTitle]  {\lingeringSpellDescription}}
              ( 6,-15) node[anchor=north east](db){\TalentBox[tier=20, width=14em, active=\distantSpellActive,    ranked=\distantSpellRanked,    name=\distantSpellTitle]    {\disguiseCastingDescription}}
              (12,-15) node[anchor=north east](dc){\TalentBox[tier=20, width=14em, active=\shapeSpellActive,      ranked=\shapeSpellRanked,      name=\shapeSpellTitle]      {\shapeSpellDescription}}
              ( 0,-20) node[anchor=north east](ea){\TalentBox[tier=25, width=14em, active=\quickenSpellActive,    ranked=\quickenSpellRanked,    name=\quickenSpellTitle]    {\quickenSpellDescription}}
              ( 6,-20) node[anchor=north east](eb){\TalentBox[tier=25, width=14em, active=\dedicationActive,      ranked=\dedicationRanked,      name=\dedicationTitle]      {\dedicationDescription}}
              (12,-20) node[anchor=north east](ec){\TalentBox[tier=25, width=14em, active=\signatureSpellActive,  ranked=\signatureSpellRanked,  name=\signatureSpellTitle]  {\signatureSpellDescription}}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

(sample copied from this file: https://github.com/luctius/genesys_dark_sun/blob/master/specialisations/arcana.tex)

I am hoping that I can create for example an `\dedicationArgs` which together form the arguments for what are the `active`, `ranked` and `name` parameters.

This means that, ideally I would like to avoid putting text directly into the pgfparameter list which are now defined in completely different files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define your `\args` inside `pdfkeys` with `myargs/.style={name=test, active=false}` instead of using a macro for that.

**Edit:** I added a pgfstyle `specialstyle` witch expects the first part of the name of these commands as parameter (e.g. `grit` or `arcanaCaster`). I just defined these commands, so the example works.
It automatically sets `name` and `active` using the commands.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\newcommand{\gritTitle}{Grit}
\newcommand{\gritActive}{true}
\newcommand{\arcanaCasterTitle}{Arcana Caster}
\newcommand{\arcanaCasterActive}{false}

\pgfkeys{
    /test/.is family, /test,
    % Here are the options that a user can pass
    default/.style = {
        name = Unnamed,
        active = false,
    },
    name/.estore in = \testName,
    active/.estore in = \testActive,
    myargs/.style={name=test, active=false},
    specialstyle/.style={
        name=\csname #1Title\endcsname,
        active=\csname #1Active\endcsname
    }
}

\newcommand\test[2][]{
    \pgfkeys{/test, default, #1}
    \noindent%
    name: \testName \\
    active: \testActive \\
    text: #2 \\
}

\begin{document}
    \test[name=test, active=false]{ipsum}

    \test[myargs]{ipsum}

    \test[specialstyle=grit]{ipsum}

    \test[specialstyle=arcanaCaster]{ipsum}
\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick solution. I'm not going to accept it just yet, because the ultimate problem is a bit more difficult. I will update my question.

Comment: This is Perfect!